# looping over an array in C

Tags: c, loops

Say I want to loop over an array, so I used a basic for loop and accessed each element in it with the index but what happens if I don't know how long my array is?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int some_array[] = {2,3,5,7,2,17,2,5};
    int i;

    for (i=0;i<8;i++){
        printf("%d\n",some_array[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is just a simple example but if I don't know how big the array is, then how can I place a correct stopping argument in the loop?

In Python this is not needed since the StopIteration exception kicks in, but how can I implement it in C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do like this:

```
for (i=0; i<sizeof(some_array)/sizeof(some_array[0]); i++){
        printf("%d\n",some_array[i]);
}
```

But do beware. It will not work if you pass the array to a function. If you want to use it in a function, then write the function so that you also pass the size as argument. Like this:

```
void foo(int *arr, size_t size);
```

And call it like this:

```
foo(some_array, sizeof(some_array)/sizeof(some_array[0]));
```

But if you have a function that just take a pointer, there is absolutely no standard way to find out the size of it. You have to implement that yourself.

Comment: thank you! any way to make it work no matter what? since this limits me quite a bit if i can't use it in functions.

Comment: @DarkLeader I wrote how to do it for functions.

Comment: can you explain why do you divide the size of the array by the sizeof the first element?

Comment: `size of the array by the sizeof the first element` - size of the array is equal to size of one element multiplied by the count of elements. So by dividing size of the array by size of one element you get...

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sizeof()` to get the size of the array in bytes then divide the result by the size of the data type:

```
size_t n = sizeof(some_array)/sizeof(some_array[0]);
```

Comment: so sizeof() function returns the size of the array in bytes? ok thank you, did not know that. why do you divide this by the first element of the array? maybe i just don't understand the second part.

Comment: @DarkLeader `sizeof(some_array)` tells you how many bytes of memory the array takes up. `sizeof(some_array[0])` tells you how many bytes a single element of the array takes up. So `sizeof(some_array) / sizeof(some_array)` gives you the number of elements in the array.  Note also that this only works for static arrays; if you dynamically allocate an array, e.g. `int *arr = malloc(sizeof(int) * 42)`, then `sizeof(arr)` returns the size of the *pointer*, not the size of the array it points to.

Comment: Just a quick side note, but `sizeof` is **not** a function. It's an operator. And that's why we don't use parenthesis unless necessary. `sizeof somearray / sizeof somearray[0]` is better.

Comment: @giusti Well, if it's better or not to skip parenthesis is subjective.

Comment: They are unnecessary. They don't contribute to claritry. The only reason they are used is because people learn to use them. It's particularly more confusing because people usually write `sizeof(type)` with no spaces, like it's a function call. So it transmit an idea that's 1000% wrong. Code should mean what it actually is. `sizeof` is an operator; parenthesis are only required for type names. Write like that.

Answer (score 2):

You **have** to know the size of the array. That's one of the most important rules of C programming. You, the programmer, are **always** responsible for knowing how large your array is. Sure, if you have a stack array or a static array, you can do this:

```
int array[size];
int size_of_array = sizeof array / sizeof *array;
for (int i = 0; i < size_of_array; i++) {
   // do something with each array[i]
}
```

But as you can see, you needed the variable `size` in the first place. So what's the point of trying to discover the size if you were forced to know it already?

And if you try to pass this array to any function

```
some_function(array); /
```

you **have** to pass the size of the array too, because once the array is no longer in the same function that declared it, there is no mechanism to find its size again (unless the contents of the array indicate the size somehow, such as storing the number of elements in `array[0]` or using a sentinel to let you count the number of elements).

```
void some_function(int *array) {
    /* Iterate over the elements until a sentinel is found.
     * In this example, the sentinel is a negative number.
     * Sentinels vary from application to application and
     * implicitly tell you the size of the array.
     */
    for (int i = 0; array[i] >= 0; i++) {
        // do something with array[i]
    }
}
```

And if it is a dynamically-allocated array, then you need to explicitly declare the number of elements anyway:

```
int size = 10;
int *array = malloc(sizeof *array * 10);
```

So, to summarize, you must always know the size of the array. There is no such thing in C as iterating over an array whose size you don't know.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can calculate the size of the array with:

```
sizeof(ArrayName)/sizeof(ArrayType)
```

but this does not work with dynamically created arrays